# SAS increment macro variable yyyymm by 1 month

Tags: sas

Basically i'm trying to get the below month4 but in a macro format.

Been a while since i've done macro functions so this is a bit tricky.

```
data test;
    input month $8.;
    datalines ;
202210
202211
202201
202210
    ;
run;



data test2;
    set test;
    format month2 date9. month3 date9.;
    test = cats(month,"01");

    month2 = input(cats(month, "01"), yymmdd8.);
    month3 = intnx("month",input(cats(month, "01"), yymmdd8.),-1);
    month4=trim(substr(put(month3,yymmddn8.),1,6));
run;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "macro format"? Is the goal to create a macro variable?  If so what macro variable? How will it be used?  Is the source in a macro variable or in a dataset like your example data?  Will have a single value or the multiple values like your example data? If multiple values how will those be shared if it is all in macro variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is what you are looking for, but your request is not very clear.

```
%let month=202212;
%let month4=%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(inputn(&month,yymmn6)),1),yymmn6);
```

It uses the INPUTN() function to convert your YYYYMM string by reading it with the YYMMN6. informat.  It then uses the INTNX() function to move to the beginning of the next month and returns the result formatted with YYMMN format so you get back another YYYYMM string of digits.

Comment: That's exactly what i was after thanks! So yymmn6 is the date format for YYYYMM? It was very hard to find it via google is this a new format?

Comment: SAS stores dates as number of days.  FORMATs are ways to DISPLAY values.  INFORMATs are ways to create values from text strings.  The YYMMN6. **FORMAT** will display a date without the day of the month as a 6 digit string.  The YYMMN **INFORMAT** will calculate a date from a 6 digit string that does not include a day of the month.